# Find the object which a property belongs to

Tags: javascript

Supposing I know an object and a property(e.g. Math and random), I can find easily **if random belongs to Math** by using

```
Math.hasOwnProperty('random');
```

***My problem is what can I do in case I know a property and I want to find in which object does it belong***. I 've done a search in stackoverflow and I found some similar questions; however I am not absolutely sure this cannot be done in some way, that's why I decided to present again this subject...

Thank you

Comment: Iterate `[Boolean, Number, Object, Function, RegExp, String, Array, Date, Error, Math, JSON]` and check if your property exists in any of them and return the first match.

Comment: Ok, but how to iterate through these built in objects since all of their properties are not enumerable? If, for example, I want to find where getDay belongs to; how may I implement this?

Answer (score 5):

Generally you cannot do this. Because you cannot access all objects defined in JavaScript codes. If you only want to evaluate properties attached to the global object `window`, then you can do this

```
for(var child in window){
    if(window[child].hasOwnProperty(foo)){
        console.log('Object ' + window[child] + ' has property foo');
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you only want to check prototype of constructor functions [but not *all* constructor functions], the idea proposed by @thefourtheye would be okay.